# AngularJs after DOM update event

Tags: angularjs

In my angularJs controller I need to load some images from the server where the controller initiializes

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $scope.baseUrl + '/edit/' + $scope.idScheda
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.scheda = response.data;

        //JQuery initialization

    }).catch(function (error, status) {
        $scope.show_error_message("Error", error.data.message);
    });
```

then I need to call a Jquery function to initialize the fresh uploaded images as a slide show

```
            var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
                loop: true,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                slidesPerView: 4,
                freeMode: true,
                watchSlidesProgress: true,
            });
            var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
                loop: true,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
                },
                thumbs: {
                    swiper: swiper,
                },
            });
```

If I run this code inside the "then" event of $http promise the DOM is not still updated and JQuery does not work.

If I inizialize JQuery component with a delay to ensure that DOM updated the issue goes away but this one is a very poor solution!

Is there an event managed by AngularJS that fires alfter DOM update?

Answer (score 0):

`$http` does following:

1. Run http request
2. Run you `then` block
3. Run `digest`

You want to run your jquery code after #3, so just queue it using native `setTimeout(..., 0)` or `$timeout(..., 0)`

P.S. Your normal angularjs code should not use that ugly jquery - create directive/component for thet, like

```
<div cool-swiper="..."></div>
```

and in onChanges you run jquery plugin with timeout just as u did.

Comment: This is what I did with  a delay of 100ms. Is there a way to intercept an event that fires when digest completes?